# Handling database files in projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Within my organisation we use a continuous integration system for deploying Ruby on Rails projects. The normal process for deploying a project is to set it up, enter the database credentials in config/database.yml and then run `git update-index --assume-unchanged config/database.yml` so local database settings won't be pushed to the server.

Recently switching between branches has been giving us `error: Entry 'config/database.yml' not uptodate. Cannot merge.` even when the -f / --force parameter is given branch changing will fail.

Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working or a better solution of handling it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add config/database.yml (And any other configuration files that differ between environments) to the .gitignore file.

You'll then need to remove the file from the git repository (Details [Here](http://source.kohlerville.com/2009/02/untrack-files-in-git/)) and manually create it on each environment.